# App.js controller issues while using state provide in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I run my application it directs to localhost:9080/#/ and the header and footer which I setup in the app.html is called:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <main id="main" class="container-fluid clear-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          //content here
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div ui-view id='content-container'></div>
  </main>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  //content here
</footer>
```

In the app.js I have the following code:

```
angular.module(constants.MODULE_NAME).controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $log, $http) {

    $scope.role = '';

    $http.get("htttp://localhost:8082/service/getUserRole")
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.role = response.data.context;
            debugger;
            if ($scope.role.toLowerCase() == "A") {
                //direct view to A dashboard
                $state.go("app.A");
            } else if($scope.context.toLowerCase() == "B"){
                //direct view to emplBoyee dashboard
                $state.go("app.B");
            }
            else{
                //do nothing
                $state.go("app");
            }});
});
```

The first page loads based on the user if it is user A then it goes to users A dashboard and if it user B then it goes to users B
dashboard.

Now in A.html and B.html there are links to go to user. The following is the code in the router.js:

```
export default ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: '/',
      template: require('./app.html'),
      controller: 'AppCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'app'
    })

    .state('app.A', {
      url: 'A',
      template: require('./A/index.html'),
      controller: 'ACtrl',
      controllerAs: 'a'
    })

    .state('app.ADetails){
      url: 'ADetails/:userId'
      template: require('./A/ADetails/index.html'),
      controller: 'ADetailsCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'adetails'
    })


    .state('app.B', {
      url: B
      template: require('./B/index.html'),
      controller: 'B',
      controllerAs: 'B'
    })
    .state('app.BDetails){
      url: 'BDetails/:userId'
      template: require('./B/BDetails/index.html'),
      controller: 'BDetailsCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'bdetails'
    });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}];
```

I am having three problems here:
1)Whenever I refresh the page app.js is called and it takes me back to the dashboard. When I am in the dashboard
page and click refresh then app.js is called again.
2)When I am in BDetailspage and click on refesh it takes me to the dashboard, I want it to be in the same page.
3) When I hit localhost:9080/#/ initially it calls the app.js and the url changes to localhost:9080/#/A.Now when i remove A and hit enter
the controller does not get called.It gets called only when I refresh the page.

Can anyone let me know how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh AppCtrl is making call to the service and changing state. Due to this your state is not restored.

Before making call to service you can check the state and make the call if required.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to fix the issues 1 and 2. But I am still having the problem with issue # 3. When I hit localhost:9080/#/ initially it calls the app.js and the url changes to localhost:9080/#/A.Now when i remove A and hit enter the controller does not get called.It gets called only when I refresh the page.

Comment: I don't think controller will be called again since that state is already initialized. May be you can listen to state change and check if you want to show A or B?